# Plotly installed but getting "no module named plotly" in jupyter notebook during import

Tags: installation, module, plotly

I had plotly installed. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled it several times because I keep getting errors.

I tried installing it through jupyter notebook and command prompt. Both of them installing the package successfully but keep getting the same error.

Lastly I used-

```html
pip install --user plotly
```

...and got it installed without any error. Here is the process in cmd-

```html
Collecting plotly
  Using cached plotly-5.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from plotly) (8.1.0)
Installing collected packages: plotly
Successfully installed plotly-5.11.0

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 22.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Satisfied with that installation I went to jupyter notebook,  tried to import-

```html
import plotly.express as px
```

...and got this error-

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8172/2395499409.py in <module>
----> 1 import plotly.express as px

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

So turns out whatever I do I keep getting the same error. It is kind of important that I install and work with plotly. Any idea how can I get it sorted?

Thanks

Comment: In the notebook where you want to import plot, make a new cell above the import statement and add to it the code `%pip install plotly`. (That includes a Jupyter/IPython magic command so make sure you have the percent sign at the start.) Run that new cell in your notebook. Hopefully it will work and give you something like `Successfully installed plotly-5.11.0 tenacity-8.1.0`. It will probably suggest to restart the kernel. **Restart the kernel** and now try your import statement.

Comment: @user19637275 Are you sure you Notebook is running in the same environment as plotly is being installed?

Comment: @Wayne I will try that and will let you guys know.

Comment: @user 19637275 I am sure about that.